# Integrity constraint violation - PHP Laravel MVC 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I've dipped my toes into Laravel PHP for the first time, but I hit an issue that I can't seem to figure out. I keep getting the following two error messages when I attempt to post information through a form (using form facade) in an attempt to create a new row in the "files" table.

> *QueryException in Connection.php line 624:* Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: files.file_description (SQL: insert into "files" ("file_title", "updated_at", "created_at") values (title test, 2015-10-02 00:18:00, 2015-10-02 00:18:00))
>
> *PDOException in Connection.php line 362:* SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: files.file_description (SQL: insert into "files" ("file_title", "updated_at", "created_at") values (tesr, 2015-10-02 00:18:00, 2015-10-02 00:18:00))

The following are my files which relate to this issue. I have populated one row using tinker, and I can edit that row just fine through a form. Creation of new rows through a form seems to be the only issue. I've looked through other threads on this matter, but I'm I haven't found any solutions in the context of my problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE 1:** I've managed slim down the errors to just integrity constraint violations on the file_title value by placing *public $timestamps = false;* into the file model as per suggested. However, I'm still struggling to fix the constraint violation on the file_title value.

**Migration File**

```
class CreateFileManagementTables extends Migration
{

public function up()
{

    Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('file_title');
        $table->string('file_name');
        $table->string('file_description');
        $table->string('file_path');
        $table->nullableTimestamps();
        $table->string('uploader_name');
        $table->double('file_size');
        $table->string('file_type');
    });

}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('files');
}
}
```

**Files Model**

```
class File extends Model {

// Mass assignment
protected $fillable = ['file_title', 'file_name', 'file_description', 'file_path', 'uploader_name', 'file_size', 'file_type'];

}
```

**Create Controller Function**

```
public function create()
{
    return view('files.create');
}
```

**Create View**

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Create a new file</h1>

   {!! Form::open(['url'=>'files']) !!}
   @include('files.form', ['submitButtonText'=>'Create file'])
   {!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this `$table->nullableTimestamps();`?

Comment: At the moment I'm planning on having users upload files, so that nullableTimestamps is there so the server can collect the upload time. I'm also under the impression that you should only specify a name for timestamps when you want user-inputted dates - not sure if that's correct.

Comment: Is this the default of your timestamps `$table->timestamps();`?

Comment: I'm new to phg laravel so I haven't done anything special like specify a DEFAULT clause with it. What you see is what I have - if I misunderstood your question, apologies in advance.

Comment: Did you overwrite the schema timestamp? using this `$table->nullableTimestamps();`?

Comment: It's probably down to my serve lack of knowledge, but I'm still not sure what you're asking. I originally had $table->Timestamps(upload_date); when I first built the app, but I changed it to $table->nullableTimestamps(); when I encouraged the errors in an attempt to fix it. I didn't modify the schema of the migration file when I ran php artisan migrate, so I probably overwritten the original timestamp because I never changed Schema::create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your migration file:

```
public function up() {

  Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('file_title');
    $table->string('file_name');
    $table->string('file_description');
    $table->string('file_path');
    $table->nullableTimestamps(); //set this to default like $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('uploader_name');
    $table->double('file_size');
    $table->string('file_type');
 });
}
```

In your model:

```
 class Files extends Model {

  public $timestamps = false; //to disable the timestamp
  // Mass assignment
  protected $fillable = ['file_title', 'file_name', 'file_description', 'file_path', 'uploader_name', 'file_size', 'file_type'];

 }
```

Comment: The good news is that doing this removed the sections of the error related to (SQL: insert into "files" ("file_title", "updated_at", "created_at") values. However, I still have _QueryException in Connection.php line 624: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: files.file_name (SQL: insert into "files" ("file_title") values (ytreytet))_ in addition to PDOException in Connection.php line 362: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: files.file_name

Comment: Check the passed parameter if it is passed to the query.

Comment: Check your file_name in your table unchecked the Not Null attribute

Comment: How do I uncheck the Not Null attribute? There doesn't seem to be any type of GUI to do that in PHP Laravel MVC. Do I just change the attribute to $table->string('file_title')->nullable(); in the migration file and run php artisan migrate?

Comment: What do you use to check if there is data in your database? aside from `var_dumping()` it?

Comment: I've just been using sqlite commands such as select * from files; from my console.

Comment: Do you have any IDE to see if the is in your database? For example: sqlyog?

Comment: I'm only using PhpStorm to edit the files. No IDE's for seeing what's in the database.

Comment: I see. Can I see the data that will pass into that query?

Comment: Ugh - now I can't add things using tinker without that getting an error too. I recreated my project since I posted this a few hours ago, but the error message is similar. http://i.imgur.com/BvVKlIV.png

Comment: Remove the `file_path` in protected fillable

Comment: Done, but still got an error. Turns out I misplaced a ' after the file_path bit. Here's a screenshot of a select * from files; once it has something in it - http://imgur.com/1M7iXDj

Comment: sorry - there was no error. I misplaced a ' which caused an error within tinker on the previous screeenshot. I've fixed that so it went through with no errors, but I still can't get the web form to create things successfully.

Comment: Maybe you can mark this if the previous problem is fixed. And add another question that will solve that problem.

Comment: What if I want timestamps on both tables?